# Grafting vegetables onto fruit-bearing trees

Tags: botany, fruit, vegetable

There are [multi-fruit trees with as many as 40 different fruit](http://mentalfloss.com/article/60243/tree-flowers-40-different-fruits), but would it be possible to graft a vegetable onto a tree?

Or maybe something in between, like grafting onto an apple tree a fruits in the botanical sense, but one of those often eaten as savory food, similar to vegetables: tomato, squash, avocado?

Comment: Some vegetables are actually fruits (like apples and bell peppers), others like carrots and potatoes are root modifications. You have to clarify what vegetables and fruits you are interested in. The type of plant is also important.

Answer (score 1):

For grafting to "take", the the two plants' vasculatures have to be organized similarly. This is not possible for two such differently organized stems as a pepper and an apple.

This is a cross section of a young woody stem (such as an apple, though this example is a tilia):

[image]

This is a cross section of an herbaceous stem (such as a pepper):

[image]

You can see there is dissimilarity in organization. Furthermore, herbaceous plant stems die back in the winter.

Even if possible, grafting an herbaceous (non-woody) stem onto a woody stem (e.g. apple) would not confer any advantage for the green pepper, a tender annual, and would be disadvantageous to the woody stemmed tree (pruning for no reason, when the branch would otherwise have produced apples, and the leaves performed their useful functions.

Comment: How about a tomato and an apple tree?

Comment: @DanDascalescu - how are a tomato and a pepper significantly different? They are both tender annuals in the nightshade family.